# Where can I find a good tutorial on XSLT files?

Tags: xslt

I'm writing a translation between two XML file types and was wondering where I could find some good tutorials about this process.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good resource for learning xsl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492529/a-good-resource-for-learning-xsl)

Answer (score 10):

### T U T O R I A L S:

**Update:** I am glad to add this **latest XSLT tutorial**:

[**XSLT 2.0 and 1.0 Foundations**](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1), By Dimitre Novatchev (8:45 hours, 12 modules)

**Also see these**:

**[What's New in XSLT 3.0: Part 1](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-3-0-whats-new-part1)**, By Dimitre Novatchev (5:28 hours, 8 modules)

**[The Evolution of XPath: What’s New in XPath 3.0](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xpath-3-0-whats-new)**, By Dimitre Novatchev (4:29 hours, 7 modules)

---

### Some tutorials by [**Norman Walsh**](https://nwalsh.com/):

1. [**On XSLT 1.0**](https://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/xsl/)
2. [**On XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0**](https://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/extreme04/)

---

### **[Link to More tutorials](https://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XSLT#Tutorials)**

---

### B O O K S

### The classic books of Michael Kay on XSLT 1.0:

[**XSLT: Programmer's Reference (Programmer to Programmer)**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764543814)

[image]

### and on XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0

[**XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference (Programmer to Programmer)**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764569090)

[image]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0764569090.01._SX140_SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg))</sub>

and

[**XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference (Programmer to Programmer)**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470192747) :

[image]

### The books by Jeni Tennison:

[**Beginning XSLT**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592603)

[image]
<sub>(source: [abebooks.com](http://isbn.abebooks.com/lbr/03/59/1590592603.jpg))</sub>

[**Beginning XSLT 2.0: From Novice to Professional**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593243)

[image]

[XSLT and XPath On The Edge, Unlimited Edition](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21J2QSDWTJL._PIsitb-dp-arrow,TopRight,21,-23_SH30_OU01_AA115_.jpg)

[image]

### And Sal Mangano's book:

[**XSLT Cookbook, Second Edition**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009747)

[image]
<sub>(source: [oreilly.com](http://oreilly.com/catalog/covers/0596003722_cat.gif))</sub>

---

### Blogs:

1. [**Michael Kay**](https://dev.saxonica.com/blog/)
2. [**David Carlisle**](https://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)
3. [**Jeni Tennison**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306045859/http://jenitennison.com/blog/rss.xml)
4. [**Dimitre Novatchev**](https://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/feed/)

---

### S I T E S

1. [**xsl-list archives**](https://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/)
2. [**Dave Pawson's XSLT-FAQ**](https://web.archive.org/web/20180512153106/http://www.dpawson.co.uk:80/xsl/)
3. [**FXSL -- the Functional Programming Library for XSLT**](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I agree on these books... specifically, Jeni Tennison for *learning* XSLT. xsl-list for getting help with those frustrating newbie issues. Also agree with @VerticalEvent... w3schools is very surfacy and sometimes inaccurate. Avoid.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed input.

Comment: @Dhanjeet You are welcome. Your feedback on any of the video-courses would be valuable.