# combining two elements into one element XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have this xml:

```
<root>

    <first>The first</first>

    <second>and the second</second>
</root>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
<root>

     <firstAndSecond>The first and the second</firstAndSecond>

</root>
```

However I cannot find any articles that demonstrate how to do this in xsl so I would be very greatful if someone could provide me with an example or link me an article that explains how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if there were three elements under the **root** element? Also, do you really want the text to be removed from the output too?

Comment: there will never be 3 elements under the root element, the first xml will always be in that format. Whoops i edited the question to include text.

Comment: Check out this old StackOverflow question which has links to useful tutorials and books; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files/3512184#3512184 (It's closed for being off-topic for StackOverflow, but the answer may give you some ideas where to look).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although probably not entirely necessary in such a simple input XML, it is usually worth starting off with the XSLT [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which on its own copies nodes as-is, meaning you only need to write templates for 'exceptions'

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In your case, you could see the problem as transforming the first child of the root into a new element, so you would have a template to match the first element

```
 <xsl:template match="/*/*[1]">
```

To create a new element with a dynamic name, use the **xsl:element** command, like so

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}And{local-name(following-sibling::*[1])}">
```

Or maybe to keep a bit more readable, use a variable in the expression

```
    <xsl:variable name="second" select="local-name(following-sibling::*[1])" />
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}And{$second}">
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here, which indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally. So, in this case **local-name()** is being evaluated to get the name of the element (excluding namespaces).

Within this you would copy the child of the two child elements across using **xsl:apply-templates** (which would handle the case where there nodes other than text to copy)

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/node()"/>
```

Finally, to stop the identity transform copying it, you would also need a template to exclude the second child of the **root**

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*[position() > 1]" />
```

Trying this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*[1]">
        <xsl:variable name="second" select="local-name(following-sibling::*[1])" />
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}And{$second}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*[position() > 1]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, this doesn't captialise the first letter. To do this (in XSLT 1.0) you will need to use a combination of **substring** to extract the first letter, and **translate** to convert it to upper case.

Comment: this is very much appreciated, thankyou for the verbose explanation +1.

Answer (score 2):

What about this solution ?

```
<root>
    <first>The first</first>
    <second>and the second</second>
</root>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="first_name" select="name(*[position() = 1])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="second_name" select="name(*[position() = 2])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="combined_names" select="concat($first_name,'And',$second_name)"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$combined_names}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(*[position() = 1],' and ',*[position() = 2])"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Couldn't the 10th line be `<xsl:value-of select="concat($first_name,' and ',$second_name)"/>`

Comment: Sorry, no. I see $first_name and $last_name are the names of the elements not the content of those elements.