# How to match elements and output HTML using XSLT?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

http://s6.postimg.org/5zzsratqp/output.jpg <--EXPECTED OUTPUT-->

Below is an XML file I have been given, whereby I need to display the data in a form using HTML, CSS, Javascript & XSLT. However, finding the tags are challenging, and with the stylesheet I have created, nothing is appearing. Any advice? Thanks

XML Data

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
<data>
    <object instance="197784" dataInstance="41" name="Give As You Earn Flex" itemNumber="1" pageNumber="1" pagesAvailable="1">
        <property id="{00fd4f20-8e9c-414f-b34f-2abd4a4dc3fe}" name="Effective Date">
            <format id="{332f8155-7253-4dc9-896c-61a3a3d19816}" answer="30/05/2014 13:39:55" />
        </property>
        <property id="{ea61f121-1c2b-47df-91af-3806eba65c4b}" name="Benefit Type ID">
            <format id="{05b7ea73-a86f-4119-b330-0a0f5a4e0143}" answer="GAYE" />
        </property>
        <object instance="197785" dataInstance="41" name="Default (GAYE)" itemNumber="1" pageNumber="1" pagesAvailable="1">
            <property id="{7f428c44-7800-4972-ad37-a005824c251f}" name="Flex Default Amount">
                <format id="{4cf95889-2249-4270-9ce0-9e2da5fedbb7}" answer="0" />
            </property>
            <property id="{cc70d36d-5700-41bf-9370-2ec34c6c7010}" name="Flex Default Cost">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
        </object>
        <object instance="197786" dataInstance="41" name="Model (GAYE)" itemNumber="1" pageNumber="1" pagesAvailable="1">
            <property id="{ea123f721-1c2b-47df-91af-3806eba65c4b}" name="Chosen Charity">
                <format id="{05b7ea73-a86f-4119-b330-0a0f5a4e0143}" answer="" />
            </property>
            <property id="{bf500440-3f1a-46ea-8937-1d8c4dfea274}" name="Flex Model Amount">
                <format id="{4cf95889-2249-4270-9ce0-9e2da5fedbb7}" answer="0" />
            </property>
            <property id="{bf9af022-ba8b-46ed-b043-573c01ba2e1d}" name="Flex Model Cost">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
            <property id="{2d94fe41-8492-4c5d-945a-a23bb5dfcf93}" name="Amount Liable for Tax">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
            <property id="{8555974b-b80e-4704-9241-867cbb435523}" name="Amount Liable for NI">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
        </object>
        <object instance="197787" dataInstance="41" name="Requested (GAYE)" itemNumber="1" pageNumber="1" pagesAvailable="1">
            <property id="{0a113492-faed-4c6e-be73-d6c14210f0b3}" name="Flex Requested Amount">
                <format id="{4cf95889-2249-4270-9ce0-9e2da5fedbb7}" answer="0" />
            </property>
            <property id="{28db97f2-9346-498d-b0b7-724535af30c4}" name="Flex Requested Cost">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
        </object>
        <object instance="197788" dataInstance="41" name="Current (GAYE)" itemNumber="1" pageNumber="1" pagesAvailable="1">
            <property id="{b0424854-bbf4-4299-080e-2480e6c09172}" name="Flex Current Amount">
                <format id="{4cf95889-2249-4270-9ce0-9e2da5fedbb7}" answer="0" />
            </property>
            <property id="{2cb5ac07-a5c7-4bfd-9b15-925a6dd5ba6c}" name="Flex Current Discount Amount">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
            <property id="{b8a7f2fe-9590-44ca-bc3d-027c76ff3dff}" name="Flex Current Value">
                <format id="{05b7ea73-a86f-4119-b330-0a0f5a4e0143}" answer="0" />
            </property>
            <property id="{e133d446-443a-419e-812f-f6506f0101db}" name="Flex Current VAT Amount">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
            <property id="{16d1795a-ad48-401e-9dc4-68f76310e238}" name="Flex Current Cost">
                <format id="{c7cf6728-47b3-4851-9633-f689b5391e88}" answer="0.0000" indicator="GBP" />
            </property>
        </object>
        <Object_ID ObjectName="Give As You Earn Flex" ParentDataInstance="47" ParentObjectInstance="197759" EmployeeObjectInstance="197993" EmployeeDataInstance="47" />
        <ChildObject_ID ChildObjectName="Default (GAYE)" ChildObjectInstance="197785" />
        <ChildObject_ID ChildObjectName="Model (GAYE)" ChildObjectInstance="197786" />
        <ChildObject_ID ChildObjectName="Requested (GAYE)" ChildObjectInstance="197787" />
        <ChildObject_ID ChildObjectName="Current (GAYE)" ChildObjectInstance="197788" />
    </object>
    <variables>
        <variable type="request.querystring" name="DP" value="47:197738/47:197759/41:197784" />
        <variable type="request.querystring" name="select" value="true" />
        <variable type="ID" name="UserRole" value="Employee" />
        <variable type="date" fulldate="14/08/2014 10:17:13" ukdate="14 August 2014" shortdate="14/08/2014" year="2014" month="8" monthname="August" day="14" timeGMT="14/08/2014 09:17:13" time="14/08/2014 10:17:13" />
    </variables>
    <options mode="Any Value" type="CoverLevel" inputName="Flex Model Amount|197786|41" modelValue="0" modelAdditionalValue="" currentValue="0" currentAdditionalValue="" formatting="Currency" suffix="Donation" minimum="1" maximum="11666.67" increment="0.01" charityName="">
        <selectionText>Please select the amount that you would like to donate per pay period:</selectionText>
        <additionalSelectionText />
        <onChange>
            validateDependants('',this.value,'No');toggleDeclarationBox(this.value)
        </onChange>
        <option value="0" location="0" cost="00" alias="No Donation" validation="No Cover" />
    </options>
</data>
```

XSLT stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>testing</h2>
     <xsl:for-each select="data">
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="property"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="data">` should be `<xsl:for-each select="data/object">`

Comment: This is a personal recommendation but have a go with PHPs XML parser. It's much, much less troublesome than XSLT as you'll need to start thinking about a template driven language rather than procedural. It can be a rather large jump

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: @JoshuaK Thank you for your response

Comment: @ScottMcGready Thank you, I will consider using the PHPs XML parser later on.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin I have now added the expected output.

Comment: @Tyson Please post your expected output **as code**, not as a picture - and post it **here**.  It's also not clear what exactly your question is. Your XSLT is a nonstarter, and "*finding the tags are challenging*" doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A note on the comments

> *but have a go with PHPs XML parser. It's much, much less troublesome than XSLT as you'll need to start thinking about a template driven language rather than procedural. It can be a rather large jump*

You received this advice in the comments, but I would disagree. Yes, XSLT may require a paradigm shift and if you can't grasp the declarative nature and functional paradigm, it can be hard, but once you get the gist of it, it'll save you a lot of time (for instance, the stylesheet below took me about 10 minutes, in imperative C# or PHP it could easily take a few hours). It is generally not a good idea to dismiss a tool or language just because it requires you to learn the tool or language, unless the alternative is so trivial that it is overkill.

Considering your input XML, I doubt your requirement is trivial and using XSLT is probably a good thing. Yes, you will need to master it, but likewise you have mastered other programming languages, and all of them come with a certain time trade-off before you can effectively use them.

[Using the Pragmatic Programmer's advice: learn a new language every year](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-a-new-programming-language-every-year), once you take the approx. one to two weeks it takes to master XSLT, you have fulfilled this year's target ;).

Some good tutorials:

- [Partially free Pluralsight training in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1) by Dimitre Novatchev, excellent starting material, it'll have you running in no time.
- [XSLT 1.0 introduction](http://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/xsl/) by Norman Walsh
- [More XSLT tutorial books and links in this SO question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files).

---

### On your code

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="data">
> ```

You have only one `data` element (XSLT does not think in tags but in elements, which is the whole from start tag to end tag and everything it contains), it does not make much sense to use for-each on it, you can simply remove this line or replace it with `xsl:apply-templates`.

> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
> ```

Since this line is inside the for-each, the focus is on the `data` element, and `name` here means "take an element named `name` that is a child of the current element, i.e. a child of `data`". Such a child doe not exist in your input. In fact, there is no element at all with the name `name`, only attributes, which you would write as `@name` in XPath (the language XSLT uses to select nodes).

> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="property"/>
> <xsl:value-of select="format"/>
> ```

While these elements do exist, they are not right beneath `data`, see previous comment.

Furthermore, if you would have the correct focus, they would still do nothing, because `xsl:value-of` takes the value of the node, which in the case of an element (between opening and closing tag, if you prefer) is the free text inside this element, to any depth. It is *not* the attributes, or comments or anything else. In your case, there is no free text in these elements, so you will select emptiness (or white space).

### A solution as a starting point to continue

Your given stylesheet example code shows you are trying out this technology and that you are struggling with concepts like focus, context node, structure, templates. To give you a head start, I have taken your input XML and made a trivial XSLT stylesheet with comments on each step.

The stylesheet works with XSLT 1.0 and up and works both inside and outside (offline processors) browsers.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <!-- from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418785/displaying-xml-data -->

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <!-- the root node, our starting point -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Hello world!</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- instruct XSLT processor to process the children and place them under <body> -->
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- what to do with elements: process their children -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- what to do if you encounter a "main" object, right under <data> -->
    <xsl:template match="data/object">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></h1>
        <h3>Properties:</h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- what to do with <property> elements -->
    <xsl:template match="property">
        <div style="margin:0">
            <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="@name" />: </span>
            <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="format/@indicator" />
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="format/@answer"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- what to do with objects-under-main-object -->
    <xsl:template match="object/object">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></h2>
        <!-- this will apply the property elements under <object> -->
        <h3>Properties:</h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- what to do with text nodes we are not interested in (default is they get output): ignore -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output when running this stylesheet offline (online you never see the output, so testing inside browsers is a pain that you really should avoid!), in my case using [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.com), but any XSLT-capable environment will do, like Visual Studio, Eclipse or Stylus Studio, is:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Hello world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Give As You Earn Flex</h1>
    <h3>Properties:</h3>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Effective Date: </span><span> 30/05/2014 13:39:55</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Benefit Type ID: </span><span> GAYE</span></div>
    <h2>Default (GAYE)</h2>
    <h3>Properties:</h3>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Default Amount: </span><span> 0</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Default Cost: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
    <h2>Model (GAYE)</h2>
    <h3>Properties:</h3>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Chosen Charity: </span><span> </span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Model Amount: </span><span> 0</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Model Cost: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Amount Liable for Tax: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Amount Liable for NI: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
    <h2>Requested (GAYE)</h2>
    <h3>Properties:</h3>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Requested Amount: </span><span> 0</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Requested Cost: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
    <h2>Current (GAYE)</h2>
    <h3>Properties:</h3>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Current Amount: </span><span> 0</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Current Discount Amount: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Current Value: </span><span> 0</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Current VAT Amount: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
    <div style="margin:0"><span style="font-weight:bold">Flex Current Cost: </span><span>GBP 0.0000</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Abel, it worked, however I should have been clearer with the expected output which I have now attached. With the given solution to establishing elements with the XML, how do I achieve the image given in the hyperlink? Thank you

Comment: @Tyson: Glad it worked. You linked to a functional design _image_.... StackOverflow is about helping you forward with _specific programming questions_. We won't do your work for you (see [ask] and [mcve]). If you have a specific issue with applying my suggestions, _show your code_ and where you are stuck in a _new question_ and we will try to help you along. If you really need someone to do the job for you, consider offline contacting me or anybody else with XSLT experience for (paid) consultancy.

Comment: @Tyson, besides, have you already tried any of the tutorials? In a few hours you know more than enough to do this job yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your input Abel, I needed direction with this task, I did not ask for it to be completed, but you have helped. I needed to understand how to achieve this and I am now nearly halfway through. I will continue to post here if I stumble across any areas I do not understand. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @Tyson: great to hear that! Feel free to ask a new question at SO, keep in mind that for us to answer to-the-point we need a minimal example input/expected output/your xslt/current output that illustrated your problem.

Comment: A comprehensive answer, and spot-on in all respects! @Tyson Please [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you also found it helpful (I cannot imagine you did not.)

Comment: @Abel totally agree with your statement regarding XSLT. Was assuming the user was probably more from a background of PHP/etc. and I certainly found XSLT a huge jump to learn for simple tasks... that being said - the same could be said about any language or tool.