# changing bgcolor of row based on existence of an attribute in xml. Each attribute will be a cell in this row

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

changing bgcolor of row based on existence of an attribute in xml. Each attribute will be a cell in this row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="abc.xsl"?>
<cars>
<toyota petrol="true" color="red" abs="true" new-feature1="true"/>
<mazda petrol="true" color="red" abs="true" new-feature2="true"/>
</cars>
```

What i am trying to do is to make a table of cars

```
<table>
<tr>toyota</tr>
<tr bgcolor="green">
<td>petrol=true</td>
<td>color=red</td>
<td>abs=true</td>
<td>new-feature1=true</td>
</tr>
<tr>mazda</tr>
<tr bgcolor="green">
<td>petrol=true</td>
<td>color=red</td>
<td>abs=true</td>
<td>new-feature2=true</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>cars</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <xsl:for-each select="cars/*">
      <tr><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></tr>
      <tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="@*">
         <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So what i want to do is to make entire row green if " new-feature*" attribute exist and if not the row should be red

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your current XSLT? Thank you!

Comment: ok will do that..please note that neither xml or xsl is the real implementation,.i ve created a smaller xml for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `xsl:if` condition to check if there is an attribute whose name starts-with "new-feature" and then use `xsl:attribute` to create a new attribute

Try this snippet

```
  <tr>
    <xsl:if test="@*[starts-with(name(), 'new-feature')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">green</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
     <xsl:for-each select="@*">
     <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
```

Note, it might actually be better to use CSS classes to define the colours. Not least because this could potentially simplify your code.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
      <style>
          .new-feature-true
          {
            background-color: green;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>cars</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <xsl:for-each select="cars/*">
      <tr><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></tr>
      <tr class="new-feature-{@*[starts-with(name(), 'new-feature')]}">
         <xsl:for-each select="@*">
         <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to generate the "class" attribute here.

Comment: worked like  a charm :D.. Thank you very much.. Can you suggest me a good tutorial page for xsl ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files/3512184#3512184 has suggestions on how to learn XSLT.