# XSL Multiplying a value times a value in an value of select

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this piece of code:

```
<xsl:value-of 
select="sum(objects/object/items/item[not(product_type='configurable' and 
count(custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']) &gt; 
0)]/custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']/value)" />
```

Which correctly outputs the integer that I want, but now in a different field, I want to mutiply this by the value of, in my case, `qty_ordered`. So what I tried is this:

```
<xsl:value-of 
select="sum(objects/object/items/item[not(product_type='configurable' and 
count(custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']) &gt; 
0)]/custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']/value * qty_ordered)" />
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I have no idea how to do this, anyone able to help me produce a line of code which outputs `id2686/value * qty_ordered`? 
`qty_ordered` is also in the items/item loop.

This is the input:

```
<items>
<item>
<qty_ordered>5.0000</qty_ordered>
```

and

```
<custom_option>
<name>Aantal pagina's in PDF</name>
<value>1</value>
<sku/>
<option_id>2686</option_id>
</custom_option>
```

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? Also, it might help if you edited your question to show a sample of your input XML. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use XSLT 2.0, and thank you for your tip, i'll do this right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, there a couple of ways to do this. One way is to create a temporary result tree which holds the individual values of `qty_ordered` and `value` for each item, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="items">
  <xsl:for-each select="item[not(product_type='configurable')]">
    <item>
      <xsl:value-of select="qty_ordered * custom_options/custom_option/value" />
    </item>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

However, in XSLT 1.0, you will need to make use of an extension function to access the nodes in the variable (as the `items` variable is of type "result tree fragment" and needs to be converted into a node set for use with the sum function). The most common one to use is exslt.

Try this XSLT (I've simplified the xpath expression for brevity)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exslt"
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:variable name="items">
      <xsl:for-each select="item[not(product_type='configurable')]">
        <item>
          <xsl:value-of select="qty_ordered * custom_options/custom_option/value" />
        </item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <result>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(exslt:node-set($items)/item)" />
    </result>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply it to this XML

```
<items>
   <item>
      <qty_ordered>5.0000</qty_ordered>
      <custom_options>
         <custom_option>
            <name>Aantal pagina's in PDF</name>
            <value>1</value>
            <sku/>
            <option_id>2686</option_id>
         </custom_option>
      </custom_options>
   </item>
   <item>
      <qty_ordered>2.0000</qty_ordered>
      <custom_options>
         <custom_option>
            <name>Aantal pagina's in PDF - Vol 2</name>
            <value>3</value>
            <sku/>
            <option_id>2687</option_id>
         </custom_option>
      </custom_options>
   </item>
</items>
```

The result is this...

```
<result>11</result>
```

**EDIT:** It's a bit difficult to explain how to integrate this in with your existing code because you haven't shown enough of your existing XSLT

But where you currently do this...

```
 <xsl:value-of 
select="sum(objects/object/items/item[not(product_type='configurable' and 
count(custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']) &gt; 
0)]/custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']/value)" />
```

You probably want to change it to this...

```
<xsl:variable name="items">
  <xsl:for-each select="objects/object/items/item[not(product_type='configurable' and count(custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']) &gt; 0)]">
    <item>
      <xsl:value-of select="qty_ordered * custom_options/custom_option[option_id='2686']/value" />
    </item>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(exslt:node-set($items)/item)" />
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the quick answer! I did indeed try it as this and it worked, but how do I implement this in an already existing code? Like does the `<xsl:template match="items">` matter? Because it's already something different. Sorry i'm new to XSL.

Comment: I've amended my answer to try and show how to implement it, but I suggest you spend some time learning about XSL first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files