# XSLT Group Elements by attribute under new parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform the following XML

I have a transformation that I need to add an additional part to.

This is the current format of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <attribute>
            <name>text12</name>
            <value>B00085590</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text34</name>
            <value>Atomos</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>date866</name>
            <value>02/21/1991</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text123</name>
            <value>brady@gmail.com</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text875</name>
            <value>123-456-7890</value>
        </attribute>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <attribute>
            <name>text12</name>
            <value>B00058478</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text34</name>
            <value>Balderas</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>date866</name>
            <value>11/24/1997</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text123</name>
            <value>balderas@yahoo.com</value>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>text875</name>
            <value>098-765-4321</value>
        </attribute>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

This is my current transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <!--Identify location of the lookup xml-->
    <xsl:param name="lookupDoc" select="document('C:\Projects\FormattedAttributes.xml')" />
    <!--Lookup Key-->
    <xsl:key name="att-lookup" match="attributes/attribute" use="name"/>
    <!--Main Template-->
    <xsl:template match="/contacts">
        <contacts>
            <!--Apply Formatted Contacts Template-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="contact" />
        </contacts>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Formatted Contacts Template-->
    <xsl:template match="contact">
        <contact>           
            <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
                <!--Create variable to hold New Name after passing the Data Name to the Lookup Key-->
                <xsl:variable name="name" select="name"/>
                <xsl:variable name="newName">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('att-lookup', $name)/mappingname"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>                     
                </xsl:variable>     
                <!--Format Contact Element with New Name variable-->
                <xsl:element name="{$newName}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </xsl:element>          
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </contact>
    </xsl:template>




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is a sample of the lookup XML used in the transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<attributes>
    <attribute folder="PERSONAL">
        <name>text12</name>
        <mappingname>ID</mappingname>
        <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
        <size>30</size>
    </attribute>
    <attribute folder="PERSONAL">
        <name>text34</name>
        <mappingname>LAST_NAME</mappingname>
        <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
        <size>30</size>
    </attribute>
    <attribute folder="PERSONAL">
        <name>date866</name>
        <mappingname>DOB</mappingname>
        <datatype>Date</datatype>
        <size></size>
    </attribute>
    <attribute folder="CONTACT_INFO">
        <name>text123</name>
        <mappingname>EMAIL</mappingname>
        <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
        <size>30</size>
    </attribute>
    <attribute folder="CONTACT_INFO">
        <name>text875</name>
        <mappingname>PHONE</mappingname>
        <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
        <size>20</size>
    </attribute>
</attributes>
```

Currently my transformation provides the following output like a charm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<contacts>
    <contact>
        <ID>B00085590</ID>
        <LAST_NAME>Brady</LAST_NAME>
        <DOB>02/21/1991</DOB>
        <EMAIL>brady@gmail.com</EMAIL>
        <PHONE>123-456-7890</PHONE>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <ID>B00058478</ID>
        <LAST_NAME>Balderas</LAST_NAME>
        <DOB>11/24/1997</DOB>
        <EMAIL>balderas@yahoo.com</EMAIL>
        <PHONE>098-765-4321</PHONE>
    </contact>
</contacts>
```

My requirements have changed and I need to change the final transformation to take the folder attribute into account and treat the ID element as an attribute for all the newly created folder parent attributes.
How do I group all the elements by attribute under a newly created folder parent?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <PERSONAL ID="B00085590">
        <LAST_NAME>Brady</LAST_NAME>
        <DOB>02/21/1991</DOB>
    </PERSONAL>
    <PERSONAL ID="B00058478">
        <LAST_NAME>Balderas</LAST_NAME>
        <DOB>11/24/1997</DOB>
    </PERSONAL>
    <CONTACT_INFO ID="B00085590">
        <EMAIL>brady@gmail.com</EMAIL>
        <PHONE>123-456-7890</PHONE>
    </CONTACT_INFO>
    <CONTACT_INFO ID="B00058478">
        <EMAIL>balderas@yahoo.com</EMAIL>
        <PHONE>098-765-4321</PHONE>
    </CONTACT_INFO>
</data>
```

Comment: The use of the "msxsl" namespace suggests you are using a Microsoft XSLT processort, and are restricted to XSLT 1.0. Is this indeed the case? (It would be much easier in XSLT 2.0, you see). Thanks!

Comment: Yes Unfortunately it is. I'm consuming a web service through SOAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this template, which involves the technique of Muenchian Grouping to get the distinct folders. The attributes for each distinct folder are then stored in a variable, and that variable is used to output the relevant attributes for contact details.

```
<xsl:template match="contact">
    <xsl:variable name="contact" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="$lookupDoc">
        <xsl:variable name="idKey" select="attributes/attribute[mappingname='ID']/name" />
        <xsl:for-each select="attributes/attribute[generate-id() = generate-id(key('folder-lookup', @folder)[1])]">
            <xsl:element name="{@folder}">
                <xsl:attribute name="ID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$contact/attribute[name=$idKey]/value" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="key('folder-lookup', @folder)" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$contact/attribute[name = $attributes/name][name != $idKey]">
                    <xsl:variable name="newName" select="$attributes[name=current()/name]/mappingname" />
                    <xsl:element name="{$newName}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                    </xsl:element>          
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>                     
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wow this works great Tim! XSLT blows me away with these transformations. I'm still very green when it comes to this. Are there any good resources that I can use to try and answer these questions for myself? I'd love to be the one answering questions one day as opposed to always asking them.

Comment: The tag info page (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) has a link to some resources at the bottom. Alternatively, there's a (closed) question on SO that has some links to books and tutorials: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files